# Run two tasks in two different workers using cluster in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process, node-sass, node-cluster

I am learning clustering in `NodeJS`. I have two tasks one is `node-sass` and another one is `uglifyjs` which I want to run by two different workers using cluster in `nodeJS`. Though the code is working file and creating the `SASS -> CSS` file and `main.js` to `main.min.js` file.

But I am not sure whether it is handled by separate workers or not. Let me know where I can make the amendments to make -

- `SASS -> CSS` handled by one worker
- `UglifyJS` task by second worker
- Once both tasks complete Master console a successful message

Following is my code:

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var fs = require('fs');
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var sass = require('node-sass');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
  });
} else {


var result = UglifyJS.minify("js/main.js");
fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/js/main.min.js', result.code, function(err){
    if(err)
        throw err;
});

sass.render({
  file: './css/main.scss',
  outFile: 'css',
}, function(err, result) { 
    if(err)
        throw err;
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/css/main.css', result.css, function(err){
        if(err)
            throw err;
    });
});

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

Comment: you should check out [grunt](https://gruntjs.org).

Comment: @meyer9 I know the webpack/grunt/gulp way...its a kind of POC I am doing for clusters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help

```
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var fs = require('fs');
var UglifyJS = require("uglify-js");
var sass = require('node-sass');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);
    cluster.fork()
        .on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
            console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        });
    cluster.fork()
        .on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
            console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        });

} else if (cluster.worker.id === 1) {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
    sass.render({
        file: './css/main.scss',
        outFile: 'css',
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/css/main.css', result.css, function (err) {
            if (err)
                throw err;
        });
    });
    process.exit();
} else {
    var result = UglifyJS.minify("js/main.js");
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + '/js/main.min.js', result.code, function (err) {
        if (err)
            throw err;
    });
    process.exit();
}
```

Comment: In this uglifyJS is running in a master process, though I want to have node the tasks handled by worker and once its get completed ..master will console success, ie. no major work for master other than forking and consoling the success message.

Answer (score 1):

In the cluster --> master-slave scenarios the real basic code, as in many parts of the original Node.js structure, is sometimes a bit more complicated than just declaring a master and slave. Here is one of the cases where I would strongly advise a couple of hours searching NPM and finding a module that will work for your schema. I have tested [cluster-master](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cluster-master) but in your case you may actually need more than one NPM module. It would be well to keep in mind that clusters usually mean cores where you are going to fork -- above code `cluster.fork();`.

You want to implement the cluster master-worker paradigm correctly and you want a return from each worker and know the process is running as you think it should. Either that means delving deep into the [Node.js cluster documentation and implementation](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html), or researching the various NPM modules available which will usually obfuscate the hard work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For poc part I tried node cluster and pm2, pm2 looks very easy to setup. pm2 also can keep the node project running in background.
Add pm2 command in your build script or just try this and see how it works

```
pm2 start app.js -i max
```

Refer
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/